# Building brick breaker but I'm not sure how to check collision with the ball and paddle

Tags: java, processing

Right now I have a code that works most of the time but my ball sometimes does not collide with the paddle or it goes directly through it and then gets stuck and disappears. It also sometimes will get unstuck and then ignore the paddle for the rest of the time. I was wonder how I could fix these problems as I am at a loss. This project is something I decided to do using processing a while back but this has definitely stumped me.

here is how I define my paddle

```
 ObjRectPaddle(){
    y = height  - 10 ;
    x = width/2;
  }

  void show (){
   rect(mouseX-size, y, size, size); 
  }

  void move(){
   x = mouseX; 
  }
```

here is how I define my ball

ObjBall(){

```
 x = width/2;
   y = height/2;
   vx = 5;
   vy = 5;
   r = 30;
  }
  //ball drawn
  void show(){
   ellipse(x, y, r, r); 
  }
  //ball movement
  void move(){
   x = x + vx; 
   y = y + vy;

   if ( x < r ||x > width){
     vx = -vx;
   }
   if ( y < r ||y > height){
     vy = -vy;
   }
```

here is my collision checking code which is in my ball class

```
 if(y > height-30 && x < height -20 && y > mouseX-paddle.size/2 && y < mouseX+paddle.size/2d ){
      vy = -vy;
      y = y + vy;
 }
```

Comment: "y > height-30" (first thing in your last bit of code)
I think that should be an x.
It also seems weird that you are comparing the y's to x's and x's to the height

Comment: @Kamakura Probably it has to be `x > mouseX-paddle.size/2 && x < mouseX+paddle.size/2d`

Comment: neither of those work

Comment: Does
`(y > height-30 && y < height -20 && x > mouseX-paddle.size/2 && x < mouseX+paddle.size/2d)`
work?